# Dropzone opens multiple file select windows

Tags: dropzone.js

I want to limit Dropzone to just select one file when you click the specified dropzone area,  but I can't find any parameters to do that.  Right now, when I select a file and hit Open,  Dropzone immediately pops up the open file dialog again without clicking, which I do not want.

Anyone run into this?  I tried setting MaxFiles=1,  but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

It attempts to place this event after declaring the JS of the dropzone.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that most probably with deleting the multiple option of the dropzone.